# Auto-Filter multiple values from array (to include them all in filter)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to auto-filter all values from an array and my code now only takes one value from the array and makes the filter.

Does anyone know how to take all values from array to filter?

thanks

```
    Set rngAF = ActiveSheet.Range("$B$4:$B$2226").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ReDim arr(1 To rngAF.Count)
    i = 1
    For Each rngCell In rngAF
        arr(i) = rngCell.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next rngCell

    Sheets("GL").Range("$A$1:$BL$10000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria1:=arr
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. when putting in the array I should have type

rngCell.Text and not rngCell.Value